# Аналог оператора sizeof из C++ в C#

Tags: c#, c++

В *С++* есть оператор `sizeof`. Есть ли что-то подобное на *С#*?

Comment: [sizeof](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/eahchzkf.aspx)

Comment: он может и есть, но в шарпе нет нужды его использовать столь повсеместно, как в ++

Comment: Есть ещё [Marshal.SizeOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof(v=vs.110).aspx). И [различия](https://ericlippert.com/2013/06/13/whats-the-difference-sizeof-and-marshal-sizeof/) между ними.

Answer (score 1):

У класса System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal есть метод SizeOf, принимающий параметр типа System.Type (также существует generic-версия), однако он не может быть использован с классами (ссылочными типами), что в общем-то логично, например:

```
using System;    
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

struct MyStruct { int a; int b; }

struct MyStructWithArray { int a; int b; int[] c; }

class MyClass { }

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf<MyStruct>()); //8
        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStructWithArray))); //16
        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf<MyClass>()); //System.ArgumentException
    }
}
```

P.S. Оператор sizeof может быть использован только с элементарными типами C# (int, byte...)